# Pass only a key into state not all object

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

i try pick only a id and set State for classId, but i got a object, how can we solve it ?

```
<Typeahead
    clearButton
    id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
    multiple
    onChange={(id) => setClassId(id)}
    labelKey="name"
    valueKey="id"
    options={[
        { id: 1, name: "10A" },
        { id: 2, name: "10B" },
        { id: 3, name: "10C" },
    ]}
    placeholder="select class"
    selected={classId}
/>;
```

I think my state will be classId = [ 1, 2, 3 ] but i got classId = [ { id: 1, name: "10A" }, { id: 2, name: "10B" }, { id: 3, name: "10C" } ]

Thanks you so much.

Comment: onChange={(option) => setClassId(option?.id)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the answers will work correctly with `multiple`, since both simply select the first item and will not return, eg: `[1, 2, 3]` as specified in the question. Instead, try:

```
<Typeahead
  ...
  onChange={(selected) => {
    const ids = selected.map(s => s.id);
    setClassId(ids);
  }}
/>
```

Note that setting `selected={classId}` will not work correctly, since none of the items will match the items passed to `options`.

See also [this related issue](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/157).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, because onChange has one parameter called "selected" which is an array. In your code is written as "id".

Please refer to their API Documentation [here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#typeahead)

If you want to get the **id** of your selected item, you can do like this:

```
<Typeahead
    clearButton
    id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
    multiple
    onChange={(arrItem) => setClassId(arrItem[0].id)}
    labelKey="name"
    valueKey="id"
    options={[
        { id: 1, name: "10A" },
        { id: 2, name: "10B" },
        { id: 3, name: "10C" },
    ]}
    placeholder="select class"
    selected={classId}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> onChange: Invoked when the set of selections changes (ie: an item is added or removed). For consistency, selected is always an array of selections, even if multi-selection is not enabled.
> (selected: Array<Object|string>) => void

documentation: [here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/HEAD/docs/API.md)

```
<Typeahead
    clearButton
    id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
    multiple
    onChange={(classes) => setClassId(classes[0].id)}
    labelKey="name"
    valueKey="id"
    options={[
        { id: 1, name: "10A" },
        { id: 2, name: "10B" },
        { id: 3, name: "10C" },
    ]}
    placeholder="select class"
    selected={classId}
/>;
```